# UIColor have wrong value on the screenshot

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, uicolor

I have code that set fill color color:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([UIColorFromRGB(0x0fb803) CGColor]));
```

where UIColorFromRGB is:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

or we can use:

```
#define UIColor10RGB(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

But on the screenshots from the iPhone instead of #97D1A1 I have #8AC98B, this colors have difference.
[image: #8AC98B, must be #97D1A1][image: #97D1A1]

Ideas?

**UPDATE**

[In this small project I have UIView with #97D1A1 background color](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyb6jy35t6ysfhb/UIColorTest.zip)

Here is screenshot: [image: Screenshot]
In screenshot I have #89C98A

Comment: ur question is not clear....Can u please make it clear?

Comment: wht do u expect from people on this question?

Comment: Colors when I see it on the screen is wrong. Why?

Comment: u might not be giving the correct rgb value

Answer (score 0):

```
RGB value of #8AC98B is 138 201 139
RGB value of #97d1a1 is (151,209,161)
```

are u giving des values

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:151.0/255.0 green:209.0/255. blue:161.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

pls do this programatically and set the view color to clear in .xib file .it will work.it works for me :)

Comment: Yes, I has tried UIColorFromRGB and UIColor10RGB with #8AC98B.But on the screenshots from the iPhone I have #97d1a1.

Comment: acc to me how is it possible to get some other color for some other rgb value

Comment: CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor10RGB(151, 209, 161) CGColor])); — on the screen I see 138 201 139

Comment: self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    if (self.isOnline)
        CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([UIColorFromRGB(0x0fb803) CGColor]));
    else
        CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([UIColorFromRGB(0x97d1a1) CGColor]));
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

Comment: show me the screenshot because if i check the rgb color in the above two images it is  totally different with wht u ssay

Comment: ya i could get wht u r saying but i dont understand why is it happening

Comment: No, it's not a correct answer. If I use CGContextSetFillColor, it's not working. And why you think that get different colors from the IB and from the code is normally?